# Android Which is better using ListView or Inflating views and adding them in a view?

Tags: android, listview, view, inflate

I have a simple question that which method is best and why ? 
 Use ListView
   or
 Innflate views and add them into a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definately use ListView, if not, why listview exists?

You have to use listviews and custom adapters.

Listviews are standard Android UI elements. All developers use listviews, so your code will be much better if someday another developer has to help / continue your code

Also listview will be more efficient.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my application, I am getting lists of vidoes, articles, offers and photos and saving them in separate arraylists. Also I have a particular sequence of displaying these 4 items. How can I use listview in this particular scnario?

Comment: @KhawarRaza you should ask that in another question but oriolpons has already alluded to the solution. You need to make your own custom listview and listviewadapter

Comment: Do you want to show all the videos / articles / photos in the same listview?

Comment: Put all the arraylist in a generic array, and in the getView function of your adapter you will have to cast them for knowing which kind of object you are showing and configure the layout with the params you want

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Do you want to scroll in the views you added? then prefer `ListView`

If you don't want to scroll within the newly added views, then consider `TableLayout` and add new rows dynamically.